# instance of a class with a body

Tags: java

//I am writing a Bluetooth application. This is the first time I see an instance of a class with a body. `DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {};` What's it? I see this for the first time so that when creating an instance of a class there was a body ? At the instance, please explain, I have not met such a design.

```
        DiscoveryListener listener = new DiscoveryListener() {

            public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
               
                devicesDiscovered.addElement(btDevice);
            }
      
            public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
           
                synchronized (inquiryCompletedEvent) {
                    inquiryCompletedEvent.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {

            }
            public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
            }
        };
```

tried the implementation of the interface

Comment: It is an anonymous, derived class. See, for example, [this tutorial over at `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5